# PHP code to send Android push notification to multiple device

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Below is the code for php in which i make a curl call to the GCM server:

```
//CODE TO SEND PUSH NOTIFICATION 
                        define('API_ACCESS_KEY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
                        $i = 0;
                        $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `my_devices`") or die($log->lwrite("Error" . mysql_error()));
                        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
                            $i = $i + 1;
                            $msg = array(
                                'message' => $resultTextValue
                            );

                            $fields = array(
                                'registration_ids' => array($row2['gcmId']),
                                'data' => $msg
                            );

                            $headers = array(
                                'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                                'Content-Type: application/json'
                            );

                            $ch = curl_init();
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
                            $result = curl_exec($ch);
                            curl_close($ch);
                        }
```

My code is under development and has max of 10 device registered. So it take decent time to make send the notificaiton to all the device.

My concern is: when the app is deployed I will be having thousands of device to send the push notification. **Won't it take a big amount of time for the push notification call?**

I am new to PHP and copied the above code from some sample application.

Comment: if you want to send the same message to a certain group of devices, you can use 'registration_ids' (all IDs you want to send the message to) and a message, this way you can send many messages in 1 call. otherwise you may have to send the messages one by one for each recipient.

Comment: @Yazan Can you please provide some code for this, i m new to php

Comment: check this question and the selected answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859898/sending-push-notifications-to-multiple-android-devices-using-gcm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first get all the Registration ids to an array

```
$regIDS = array(); // set variable as array

  // get all ids in while loop and insert it into $regIDS array
 while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
array_push($regIDS ,$row2['gcmId'])
}
```

then in $fields, mention the array variable name **$regIDS** instead of **array($row2['gcmId']**

```
$fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $regIDS ,
        'data' => $msg
 );
```

and you are now able to send msg to multiple device in a single push Notification Message.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

example pic=

here i have only two regIDs in database so here Success=2 in only one call of push notification

[image]

Comment: what if message is different for each token?