# Parse Receiver android code after sending push from php

Tags: php, push-notification, push, android-notifications, parse-android-sdk

I have a PHP code to send push notification, PHP script returns `{"result":true} but its not displayed on the device. I think I need to write a custom receiver code. I have the Receiver class as:

```
package com.phpand;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class ParseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = ParseReceiver.class.getName();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String message = extras != null ? extras
            .getString("customdata") : "";
    JSONObject jObject;
    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(message);
        Log.d(TAG,
                jObject.getString("alert")
                        + jObject.getString("action"));
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

and the Manifest as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.phpand"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name=".permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.phpand.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.phpand.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.phpand.ParseMainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


     </activity>
   <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.phpand.ParseReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.MyStuff.stuff" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Can anyone help me get out from this.
Note: All Push messages are displayed on dashboard of parse.com

Comment: I think its the first two lines inside onReceive where is the intent getting saved.

Comment: If you are using parse to send notification then you have to implement custom receiver which implement `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`

Comment: @ved ~ tried too with the same, but failed to receive.

Comment: GCM or Parse Push ??

Comment: I am using Parse Push