# how to implement custom mobile push service

Tags: php, websocket, push-notification, ionic-framework

i just need to get some information about a solution i'm trying to implement.I have to write a push service that can be used to push messages to android and ios apps the project is an ionic app.

So far i have come across Google Cloud Messaging ,Firebase ,Pusher ,push.ionic.io but all of them are third party.

Is there any documentation that explain how to make such a push service using php.I have previously worked using rachet for websocket.As i understand this type of service must be based on websocket.

Comment: why android tag is used here?

Comment: since the push must support android

Comment: but you mentioned you want make service in php

Comment: yes the service will be in php. broadcasted to both android and ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various resources available out there regarding implementation of Push Notification services in php. Let me point you to couple of those.

1. [Simple Push service in php](https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017)
2. [Have a look at this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859898/sending-push-notifications-to-multiple-android-devices-using-gcm)

So if your concern is implememnting Push noification on client side using ionic. You can use ngCordova's cordovaPush. You can find it [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/).

cordovaPush really works great both for android and iOS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it seems that one way or the other the , solution have to depend on a third party service to do the actual push

Comment: @ShalithaVikum - Unless you only push messages while the application is open, you will have to use either Apple's or Google's Notification (Push) system... If each app on your phone held open tcp/ip sockets transmitting and receiving 24/7, you battery might not survive for as long as you might think...

Comment: @Myst exactly the problem i have

Comment: @ShalithaVikum - I guess you can look at it as a problem... but it is a "feature", not a "bug". Apps really shouldn't be running in the background wasting your battery and resources without you knowing, at least not for any meaningful period of time... Apple and Google offer these services (which are, after all, free) to help all of us - clients and developers alike - to provide and enjoy the best user experience possible.