# how to send notification automatically to my android app users, when there is new row added in my database table

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing campus Hub android app(which have student information, results, notifications from the administration etc). How to alert my app users when there is a new notification from the administration(when administration post a notice it directly adds a row to my notices table).  I want send this notification automatically when there is new notice in my notices table. notices table is there in a external database

Comment: if the table is in sqlite mobile database then using previous count < current count we can show notification , if the database is from backend server side we can show notification using GCM push notifications.

Comment: could you please explain me(or send me a link) how to send notification using GCM.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ please go through this link , and we have to write server side code also to achieve gcm push notifications

Answer (score 0):

After successful insert send the notification from admin end to the app and handle that notification at the app end.

Answer (score 0):

Usual steps are:

1. Create a Google API Project
2. Enable GCM for your Project
3. Link Android App
4. Deploy a Droplet
5. Set Up Python GCM Simple Server
6. Send a Push Notification

This list is from example:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-server-to-send-push-notifications-with-gcm-to-android-devices-using-python

This example using payton on server side. You will need to find example prior to language you are using on your server but other steps are independent on language itself. This is usually task with less or more problems, so once you start using this tutorial for example, you will find concrete problems you have to solve.

Comment: I am using PHP on server side. could you share a link which sends push notification using php on server side

Comment: https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859898/sending-push-notifications-to-multiple-android-devices-using-gcm http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139 and many more....

Comment: So @SandeepSamudrala is those answers helped you in anyway. Do you plan to downvote, upvote or accept any answer of this, or to comment if it helped or not?

Comment: no, can't we send push notification automatically? I have referred androidhive link in that he is getting list of users in the web page from that he manually sending notification to each user. I need automatic push notifications (when we insert a new row in database table, it should notify the user). I am using php as server side script and mysql as database..