# send notification to android as soon as update take place in MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql

In my android app a new user initially registers himself with the app then if the user is approved by the admin from back-end then only he will be able to login.Now,what i want is as soon as admin approve the user, a notification should appear in android mobile telling the user that now he can login successfully as he has been approved.I have stored my data in MySQL database in web server.Now i have no idea how to implement this.Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: what you have tried for you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859898/sending-push-notifications-to-multiple-android-devices-using-gcm

Comment: I don't have idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to store the user's device token while user register in the system.
And when admin make the user active from backend you should have to send notification to user by FCM service on the device token.

If you don't have idea about FCM please visit : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Please found the push notification sending code from PHP below.

```
function sendFCMPushnotification($arr) {
    $device_token = $arr['device_token'];
    $message = $arr['message'];

    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $fields = array (
            'registration_ids' => array (
                    $device_token
            ),
            'data' => array (
                "message" => $message,
                "sound"    =>  "default"
            ),
            'notification' => array(
                'body'  => $message,
                'title' =>  'ProjectName',
            )
    );

    $fields = json_encode ( $fields );    
    $headers = array (
            'Authorization: key=' . "PUT_YOUR_FCM_Key",
            'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

    $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
    var_dump($result);
    curl_close ( $ch );
}
$arr = [
    'device_token'  =>  "PLACE_YOUR_DEVICE_TOKEN",
    'message'  =>  'PLACE_YOUR_MESSAGE',
];
sendFCMPushnotification($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all integrate push notification service in you app.
Then from server side you need to send push notification as you approved credential so user will get push notification on app.